# How to retrieve paricular value from map which contains list?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am retrieving the list and want a particular column say `date` from that list which I am getting but in that particular column, I want date which is of the year 2019 only as that column contains both year 2018 & 2019.

```
Iterator<Map<String, Object>> itr = listEnquiry.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    map = itr.next();
    CustomerBean bean = (CustomerBean) map.get("customerBean");
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String date = simpleDateFormat.format(bean.getCustomerCreationDate());   // it is giving me date column which contains both year.
}
```

The output which I am getting is-

```
2018-12-30
2018-12-30
2019-03-13
2018-12-30
```

But I want the output like that

```
2019-03-13
```

So How can I acieve this. I am unable to do.

Comment: Calendar has a get()-method where you can ask for the year of the date: get(Calendar.YEAR). If your date is of type Date you can create a Calendar-object and use setTime(date) to put the date in the calendar. When you know the year you can use it in an if-statement.

Comment: The `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date`, and `Calendar` classes are terrible and should never be used. They were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes. See `LocalDate` and JDBC 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `bean.getCustomerCreationDate()` returns a `java.util.Date` object then try adding the following inside your while loop at the bottom:

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map1.put("customerBean",new CustomerBean("2018-12-30") );
        HashMap<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map2.put("customerBean",new CustomerBean("2018-03-13") );
        HashMap<String, Object> map3 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map3.put("customerBean",new CustomerBean("2018-12-30") );
        HashMap<String, Object> map4 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map4.put("customerBean",new CustomerBean("2019-03-01") );
        HashMap<String, Object> map5 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map5.put("customerBean",new CustomerBean("2017-05-16") );
        HashMap<String, Object> map6 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map6.put("customerBean",new CustomerBean("2019-01-23") );

        ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> listEnquiry = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
        listEnquiry.add(map1);
        listEnquiry.add(map2);
        listEnquiry.add(map3);
        listEnquiry.add(map4);
        listEnquiry.add(map5);
        listEnquiry.add(map6);

        ArrayList<CustomerBean> newValues = new ArrayList<>(); //List will contain all objects with 2019 values
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        Iterator<Map<String, Object>> itr = listEnquiry.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Map<String, Object> map = itr.next();
            CustomerBean bean = (CustomerBean) map.get("customerBean");
            //String date = simpleDateFormat.format(bean.getCustomerCreationDate());   // it is giving me date column which contains both year.

            String date = "";
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(bean.getCustomerCreationDate()); 
            if (cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)==2019) {
                 date = simpleDateFormat.format(bean.getCustomerCreationDate());
                 newValues.add(bean);
                 //System.out.println(date); Simple print the date
            }           
        }
        newValues.forEach((v)->System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(v.getCustomerCreationDate())));
    }

    private static class CustomerBean {

        Date date = new Date();

        public CustomerBean(String date) {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            try {
                this.date = format.parse(date);
            } catch (ParseException e) {}
        }

        public Date getCustomerCreationDate() {
            return this.date;
        }

    }

}
```

This gives me the output

```
2019-03-01
2019-01-23
```

Comment: If my first date from list is of 2018 then it is not working as it cannot go further to check next data

Comment: I have reconstructed an example of your bean object and the Map and List iteration. This filters and gives me the year 2019 objects only. I edited the answer above with the full class code